# Raspberry Pi 3B+ Service working without Audio

Tags: python, linux, audio, raspberry-pi, output

I've created a python program which is designed to run on a headless raspberry pi that requires the use of speakers and a microphone. I've set it to launch as a service and it shows the service is active with no errors but when it's launched at boot up, there's no audio coming from the program but it works when it's run as a regular python program in IDE.

My service under /etc/systemd/system/deskBuddy.system looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description = Launches my python program
After = network.target sound.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3 /home/rdp/deskBuddy.py
WorkingDirectory = /home/rdp
StandardOutput = inherit
StandardError = inherit
Restart = always
User = rdp

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

My Python file runs openai, pyttsx3, speech_recognition and sounddevice

I've tried to run it in rc.local but that doesn't work either